# How to auto open App with react-open-app?

Tags: reactjs

I'm had tried using react-open-app module in my web with reactjs to open my react-native app.
But, how I can auto open the app with deep link on react-open-app without click button?

Here, the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import OpenApp from "react-open-app";

class OpenApps extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Please open link on bottom</h1>
                <OpenApp android="example://notif" >Open My App (click this link)</OpenApp>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default OpenApps;
```

as You can see, I must click the "Open My App (click this link)"  link to open my app,
and how I can auto open app without click the link?

Thanks for your help :)